# NativeScript 7 with sqlite and typeorm

Tags: webpack, nativescript, typeorm, nativescript-angular

For a little test project i've tried to start a NativeScript (Angular flavor) with a sqlite db and typeorm.

```sh
ns create sample-typeorm --ng
cd sample-typeorm
ns plugin add nativescript-sqlite
npm i typeorm stream-browserify timers-browserify
```

Because of the missing nodejs modules "stream" and "timers" my `tsconfig.json` looks like

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "app/*"
      ],
      "timers": [
        "node_modules/timers-browserify"
      ],
      "stream": [
        "node_modules/stream-browserify"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/tests/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.ios.ts",
    "src/**/*.android.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./references.d.ts",
    "./src/main.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "platforms",
    "e2e"
  ]
}
```

To start the typoeorm/sqlite test, i added in my `src/main.ts` the "createConnection" stuff:

```js
// this import should be first in order to load some required settings (like globals and reflect-metadata)
import {platformNativeScriptDynamic} from "@nativescript/angular";

import {AppModule} from "./app/app.module";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm/browser";

let driver = require('nativescript-sqlite');

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);


(async () => {
    try {
        const connection = await createConnection({
            database: 'test.db',
            type: 'nativescript',
            entities: [
                //... whatever entities you have
            ],
            driver,
            logging: true,
            synchronize: false
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
    ;
})();
```

I startet the app

```sh
ns run ios --emulator
```

After a little bit of working time for the build system the following error appear:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/app-root-path/lib/resolve.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/private/tmp/sample-typeorm/node_modules/app-root-path/lib'
 @ ../node_modules/app-root-path/lib/resolve.js 7:18-35
 @ ../node_modules/app-root-path/lib/app-root-path.js
 @ ../node_modules/app-root-path/index.js
 @ ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.js
 @ ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/index.js
 @ ./main.ts
```

In the `node_modules/app-root-path/lib/resolve.js` is the source of the error:

```js
var globalPaths = require('module').globalPaths;
```

Is there a browserify equivalent for the "module" module? Or is there an option for the webpack to avoid this error?

To get a step forward i modified the `resolve.js` to skip the "module" and ran into the next error, which let me thinking about that i have another missing/miss configured webpack option:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'env' of 'global.process' as it is undefined.
at
../node_modules/supports-color/index.js(file: node_modules/supports-color/index.js:6:7)
```

In the `node_modules/supports-color/index.js` is this:

```js
const {env} = process;
```

The `webpack.config.js` is untouched from the "ns create ...".
Have anyone a running typeorm sample for NativeScript 7? Or an idea which module is missing?

Comment: I am stuck at the same spot however I didn't add broswerify versions of streams and timers. Instead I used the following ns nodeify plugin, natievscript-xml2js lib, @nativescript-community/typeorm lib. I also tried `npm i module` which lead to your last error. Typeorm is a great lib lets hope someone can shed light on how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get it working by downgrading typeorm to version 0.2.25. I found the build starts throwing errors from tyeporm 0.2.26 onwards (not sure what the issue is there). Here is what my package.json looks like, all other starter template files were untouched.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@nativescript/template-blank-ng",
  "main": "main.js",
  "displayName": "Blank",
  "templateType": "App template",
  "version": "7.0.8",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nstudio",
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "angular",
    "{N}",
    "tns",
    "template",
    "category-general"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.0",
    "nativescript-nodeify": "^0.8.0",
    "nativescript-sqlite": "^2.6.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "typeorm": "0.2.25",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~4.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

The code (OrmConfig.ts) to start the db is as follows:

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm/browser';
import { LocalAppUser } from './home/LocalAppUser';

// need the commercial version for types
const driver = require('nativescript-sqlite');

export class OrmConfig {

    static async init(): Promise<void> {
        try {

            const connection = await createConnection({
                //multithreading: true,
                database: 'local.db',
                type: 'nativescript',
                driver,
                entities: [
                    LocalAppUser
                ],
                logging: ["schema","error"]
            });
            // setting true will drop tables and recreate
            await connection.synchronize(false);

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

}
```

which is loaded in main.ts like so

```
// this import should be first in order to load some required settings (like globals and reflect-metadata)
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "@nativescript/angular";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { OrmConfig } from './app/OrmConfig';

(async () => {
    await OrmConfig.init();
})();

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```